# Does Google Maps Android API locate me automatically?

Tags: android, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working with Google Maps Android API V2.

When my map fragment is loaded it shows my location automatically (with the blue dot). Why does this happen? Is my location history affecting or is the default working mode?

Does this code cause it?:

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
        }
});
```

I have commented this piece of code but the map is still showing the blue dot.

If this is not happening because of the history, would this piece of code be enough to get user location or do I need to use LocationManager class as described in other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true/false);
```

to control showing your location on map. I think it is enough to turn the setting on to make your location work with Google Maps, without need to use LocationManager etc.